# MySQL: cleanup data by removing/aggregating duplicates and constant values

Tags: mysql, aggregate

In a large database with measurement and status data I intend to reduce the data without loosing to much information. I studied several examples but my SQL skills seem to be too limited to succeed...

The table has several millions of data. The table definition is

```
TIMESTAMP TIMESTAMP, DEVICE varchar(32), TYPE varchar(32), EVENT varchar(512), READING varchar(32), VALUE varchar(32), UNIT varchar(32)
```

Some example data. The full table has many different DEVICES and READINGS which should each be handled individually:

```
+---------------------+----------+------+---------+---------+-------+------+
| TIMESTAMP           | DEVICE   | TYPE | EVENT   | READING | VALUE | UNIT |
+---------------------+----------+------+---------+---------+-------+------+
| 2016-03-27 10:17:45 | KNX_428c | KNX  |  49 mA  | state   | 49    | mA   |
| 2016-03-27 10:19:45 | KNX_428c | KNX  |  47 mA  | state   | 47    | mA   |
| 2016-03-27 10:21:44 | KNX_428c | KNX  |  50 mA  | state   | 50    | mA   |
| 2016-03-27 10:23:44 | KNX_428c | KNX  |  50 mA  | state   | 50    | mA   |
| 2016-03-27 10:23:44 | KNX_428c | KNX  |  50 mA  | state   | 50    | mA   |
| 2016-03-27 10:25:44 | KNX_428c | KNX  |  50 mA  | state   | 50    | mA   |
| 2016-03-27 10:25:44 | KNX_428c | KNX  |  50 mA  | state   | 50    | mA   |
| 2016-03-27 10:27:44 | KNX_428c | KNX  |  50 mA  | state   | 50    | mA   |
| 2016-03-27 10:27:44 | KNX_428c | KNX  |  50 mA  | state   | 50    | mA   |
| 2016-03-27 10:29:44 | KNX_428c | KNX  |  50 mA  | state   | 50    | mA   |
| 2016-03-27 10:31:44 | KNX_428c | KNX  |  50 mA  | state   | 50    | mA   |
| 2016-03-27 10:31:44 | KNX_428c | KNX  |  47 mA  | state   | 47    | mA   |
| 2016-03-27 10:33:44 | KNX_428c | KNX  |  50 mA  | state   | 50    | mA   |
| 2016-03-27 10:33:44 | KNX_428c | KNX  |  50 mA  | state   | 50    | mA   |
| 2016-03-27 10:34:04 | KNX_428c | KNX  |  136 mA | state   | 136   | mA   |
| 2016-03-27 10:34:04 | KNX_428c | KNX  |  165 mA | state   | 165   | mA   |
| 2016-03-27 10:34:05 | KNX_428c | KNX  |  136 mA | state   | 136   | mA   |
| 2016-03-27 10:34:05 | KNX_428c | KNX  |  107 mA | state   | 107   | mA   |
| 2016-03-27 10:34:05 | KNX_428c | KNX  |  79 mA  | state   | 79    | mA   |
| 2016-03-27 10:34:06 | KNX_428c | KNX  |  50 mA  | state   | 50    | mA   |
| 2016-03-27 10:34:29 | KNX_428c | KNX  |  107 mA | state   | 107   | mA   |
| 2016-03-27 10:34:29 | KNX_428c | KNX  |  136 mA | state   | 136   | mA   |
| 2016-03-27 10:34:30 | KNX_428c | KNX  |  165 mA | state   | 165   | mA   |
| 2016-03-27 10:34:30 | KNX_428c | KNX  |  139 mA | state   | 139   | mA   |
| 2016-03-27 10:34:30 | KNX_428c | KNX  |  107 mA | state   | 107   | mA   |
| 2016-03-27 10:34:31 | KNX_428c | KNX  |  51 mA  | state   | 51    | mA   |
| 2016-03-27 10:34:44 | KNX_428c | KNX  |  0 mA   | state   | 0     | mA   |
| 2016-03-27 10:35:44 | KNX_428c | KNX  |  0 mA   | state   | 0     | mA   |
| 2016-03-27 10:37:44 | KNX_428c | KNX  |  0 mA   | state   | 0     | mA   |
| 2016-03-27 10:37:44 | KNX_428c | KNX  |  0 mA   | state   | 0     | mA   |
| 2016-03-27 10:39:43 | KNX_428c | KNX  |  0 mA   | state   | 0     | mA   |
| 2016-03-27 10:41:43 | KNX_428c | KNX  |  0 mA   | state   | 0     | mA   |
| 2016-03-27 10:43:43 | KNX_428c | KNX  |  0 mA   | state   | 0     | mA   |
| 2016-03-27 10:45:43 | KNX_428c | KNX  |  0 mA   | state   | 0     | mA   |
| 2016-03-27 10:47:43 | KNX_428c | KNX  |  0 mA   | state   | 0     | mA   |
| 2016-03-27 10:47:43 | KNX_428c | KNX  |  0 mA   | state   | 0     | mA   |
| 2016-03-27 10:49:43 | KNX_428c | KNX  |  0 mA   | state   | 0     | mA   |
```

I intend to do two things:

- Aggregate the values with same timestamp,device,reading using max()
- Remove consecutive identical values, except the first and the last in sequence of constant values.

The first thing I achieved in a select statement with group. But I have no idea how to actually change the database.

```
SELECT *,MAX(VALUE) FROM filelog
GROUP BY TIMESTAMP,DEVICE,READING
```

For the second step I found several examples, but they always combine the duplicates in one single record and not in two (first and last) as I intend to do it. And usually these example work with JOIN which I think is not possible with multi-millions datasets.

The result shall be as below:

```
| 2016-03-27 10:17:45 | KNX_428c | KNX  |  49 mA  | state   | 49    | mA   | 
| 2016-03-27 10:19:45 | KNX_428c | KNX  |  47 mA  | state   | 47    | mA   | 
| 2016-03-27 10:21:44 | KNX_428c | KNX  |  50 mA  | state   | 50    | mA   | 
| 2016-03-27 10:33:44 | KNX_428c | KNX  |  50 mA  | state   | 50    | mA   | 
| 2016-03-27 10:34:04 | KNX_428c | KNX  |  136 mA | state   | 165   | mA   | 
| 2016-03-27 10:34:05 | KNX_428c | KNX  |  136 mA | state   | 136   | mA   | 
| 2016-03-27 10:34:06 | KNX_428c | KNX  |  50 mA  | state   | 50    | mA   | 
| 2016-03-27 10:34:29 | KNX_428c | KNX  |  107 mA | state   | 136   | mA   | 
| 2016-03-27 10:34:30 | KNX_428c | KNX  |  165 mA | state   | 165   | mA   | 
| 2016-03-27 10:34:31 | KNX_428c | KNX  |  51 mA  | state   | 51    | mA   | 
| 2016-03-27 10:34:44 | KNX_428c | KNX  |  0 mA   | state   | 0     | mA   | 
| 2016-03-27 10:49:43 | KNX_428c | KNX  |  0 mA   | state   | 0     | mA   |
```

Thanks for your support.

Comment: Your second requirement is not clear to me.  Can you show what you mean by using sample data?

Comment: Number of records are irrelevant for a join operation. But I do not really think you need one anyway. It may be easier to copy the records you want to keep to another table and remove the original data.

Comment: Is the second step clear now with the expected result?

Answer (score 0):

For the first query, if you want to obtain the full records after aggregation, you will need to do more work than what you suggested.  One approach would be to do an additional join:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM filelog t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT TIMESTAMP, DEVICE, READING, MAX(VALUE) AS VALUE
    FROM filelog
    GROUP BY TIMESTAMP, DEVICE, READING
) t2
    ON t1.TIMESTAMP = t2.TIMESTAMP AND
       t1.DEVICE    = t2.DEVICE    AND
       t1.READING   = t2.READING   AND
       t1.VALUE     = t2.VALUE
```

Comment: Nice, but what is the difference? I have to do MAX(CAST(VALUE AS DECIMAL) in order to have the correct max for the data at 2016-03-27 10:34:05. But this does not change the data in filelog itself isn't it?

Comment: After further study I realise that this answer is wrong. It reports the records without duplicates. What is asked for was a statement which permanently removes dupplicate reports from the database and replaces them with a new record with the maximum value.